# Compare the value change of data in Excel between two similar sheets without VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I need to match data in the `column A`'s of two different sheets with similar data and then compare the values in `column C`. `sheet 1` features data from this month, `sheet 2` from last month.

I have `column A` of `sheet 1` and `column A` of `sheet 2` both have a lot of the same values, but in a different order.

Both `column C`'s have numerical values. I'd like to indicate the change in numerical values by highlighting the cell in `column C` in red (decrease), green (increase), keeping the color the same if there is no change or if it's a new value.

I only need to color the newer sheet (`sheet 1`). See the image.

Can this be done without VBA (or with really simple VBA)?

[image: comparison of two sample sheets]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use conditional formatting combined with a vlookup.

Select cells C2:C6 in sheet 1 click conditional formatting, goto new rule, select "Use a formula to determine which cell gets formatted.  A formula to see if the sheet1 value is bigger would be.

```
=C2>VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$5,3,FALSE)
```

Then set your formatting below.

The way conditional formatting works this will update to =C3... or =C4... for the cells below the first one so they should all format correctly.

You can add multiple conditional formatting if you want to check for lower numbers as well.

Comment: `VLOOKUP()` is such a useful function!